# How do I load firebase data into react-redux asynchronously?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux

I am currently trying to load my product data into redux, but so far I cant seem to pass the product information returned from firestore into the reducer.

Index.js -> load first 10 products from firestore soon after store was created.

```
store.dispatch(getAllProducts)
```

action/index.js

```
import shop from '../api/shop'

const receiveProducts = products => ({
  type: types.RECEIVE_PRODUCTS
  products
})

const getAllProducts = () => dispatch => {
  shop.getProducts(products => {
     dispatch(receiveProducts)
  })
}
```

shop.js

```
import fetchProducts from './firebase/fetchProducts'

export default {
   getProducts: (cb) => cb(fetchProducts())
}
```

fetchProducts.js

```
const fetchProducts = async() => {
   const ProductList = await firebase_product.firestore()
      .collection('store_products').limit(10)

   ProductList.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
      const tempDoc = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
         return { id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }
      })
   }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log('Error getting Documents: ', error)
   })
}
```

In product reducers

```
const byId = (state={}, action) => {
   case RECEIVE_PRODUCTS: 
      console.log(action); <- this should be products, but it is now promise due to aysnc function return?
}
```

I can get the documents with no issues (tempDocs gets the first 10 documents without any issue.) but I am not able to pass the data back into my redux. If I were creating normal react app, I would add a loading state when retrieving the documents from firestore, do I need to do something similar in redux as well ?

Sorry if the code seems messy at the moment.

Comment: I think you need to take a look to redux-saga [https://redux-saga.js.org/](https://redux-saga.js.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetchProducts` is an async function so you need to wait for its result before calling `dispatch`. There are a few ways you could do this, you could give `fetchProducts` access to `dispatch` via a hook or passing dispatch to `fetchProducts` directly.

I don't quite understand the purpose of `shop.js` but you also could `await` `fetchProducts` and then pass the result of that into dispatch.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. So I am assuming I have to create a middleware to wait for the async function ?  Something like this https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-6-async-logic

Comment: "Create a middleware" sounds more formal than what I'm suggesting. All I'm saying is that dispatch just needs to be called *after* the results from firestore come back. And there are a few different places I can think of doing that waiting which I suggested above.

Comment: I got it working ! I did not know that you could dispatch the result directly. Appreciate your  help,

Answer (score 1):

A generalized routine I use to accomplish exactly this:

```
const ListenGenerator = (sliceName, tableName, filterArray) => {
  return () => {
    //returns a listener function
    try {
      const unsubscribe = ListenCollectionGroupQuery(
        tableName,
        filterArray,
        (listenResults) => {
          store.dispatch(
            genericReduxAction(sliceName, tableName, listenResults)
          );
        },
        (err) => {
          console.log(
            err + ` ListenGenerator listener ${sliceName} ${tableName} err`
          );
        }
      );
      //The unsubscribe function to be returned includes clearing
      // Redux entry
      const unsubscriber = () => {
        //effectively a closure
        unsubscribe();
        store.dispatch(genericReduxAction(sliceName, tableName, null));
      };

      return unsubscriber;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(
        `failed:ListenGenerator ${sliceName} ${tableName} err: ${err}`
      );
    }
  };
};
```

The `ListenCollectionGroupQuery` does what it sounds like; it takes a `tableName`, an array of filter/.where() conditions, and data/err callbacks.

The `genericReduxAction` pretty much just concatenates the sliceName and TableName to create an action type (my reducers de-construct action types similarly).  The point is you *can* put the dispatch into the datacallback.

Beyond this, you simply treat Redux as Redux - subscribe, get, etc just as if the data were completely local.